# Adjusting CSS Element to Eliminate Overlay

Tags: html, css, dynamic

In my current HTML project I am using a side navigation bar for website navigation. If I scroll to the right too much on the page however the side navigation bar will overlay onto the body text of the page. How to I keep the side bar from adjusting for the view-port present in the browser. Here are some screenshots and my code for the page.

http://cjcahala.imgur.com/all/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>cjcahala.net</title>
<style>
* {
font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
}
/***********************************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn {
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}
.btn:hover {
background: #3cb0fd;
text-decoration: none;
}
.btn2 {
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
background: #3498db;
}
.btn2:hover {
background: #3cb0fd;
text-decoration: none;
}
.top {
position:absolute;
left:178px; right:0;
height: 92px;
margin:auto;
}
.left {
position: fixed;
left:0; top:0; bottom: 0;
width: 125px;
background: #3498db;
margin:auto;
}
.main {
position: absolute;
left:125px; top:92px; right:0; bottom:0;
width:400px;
margin:auto;
}
p {
position:relative;
left:20px;
}
.peppy {
position:relative;
left:10px;
}
}
/***********************************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn {
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}
.btn:hover {
background: #3cb0fd;
text-decoration: none;
}
.btn2 {
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
background: #FFFF00;
}
.btn2:hover {
background: #3cb0fd;
text-decoration: none;
}
.top {
position:absolute;
left:178px; right:0;
height: 92px;
}
.left {
position: fixed;
left:0; top:0; bottom: 0;
width: 178px;
background: #3498db;
}
.main {
position: absolute;
left:178px; top:92px; right:0; bottom:0;
width:400px;
}
p {
position:relative;
left:20px;
}
.peppy {
position:relative;
left:10px;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left">
<a class="btn" href="./index.html">Home</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="./about.html">About</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="./contact.html">Contact</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="./media.html">Media</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="http://cjcahala.tumblr.com/">Blog</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="./donate.html">Donate</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-related="cjcahala" data-hashtags="cjcahala">Share This Page On Twitter</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=cjcahala" data-related="cjcahala">Tweet #cjcahala</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/cjcahala" data-show-count="false">Follow Me @cjcahala</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=cjcahala" data-related="cjcahala">Tweet To Me @cjcahala</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/cjcahalparaolympic" data-action="like" data-send="true">Like Me On Facebook</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdUcO0wCP3Fu2RbF8uo-iCQ/featured">Subscribe To My Youtube Feed</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="https://plus.google.com/109790307919254113898/posts">Add Me To Your Google Plus Circle</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="http://cjcahala.tumblr.com/">Follow Me On Tumblr</a><br><br>
<a class="btn" href="http://instagram.com/cj_cahala">Follow Me On Instagram</a><br><br>
</div>
<div class="main">
<h1 class="peppy">Hello There</h1>
<p>
Thanks for taking the time to check out my site. I am an aspiring paralympic athlete with some big goals for the future. I come from a blue collar home and the world of snowboarding is a really expensive one. Check out the website, take a look at my videos,  or email me, and of course be social. If you are feeling particularly awesome today, you can even donate below.
</p>
<p>
<a class="btn2" href="https://adaptiveadventures.webconnex.com/2013donate">Awesomeness-Infused Donate Button</a>
</p>
<h1 class="peppy">About Me</h1>
<p>
Hello, my name is CJ Cahala and I am hoping to accomplish a dream. It was always a thought in the back of my head of being a paralympic athlete, living life on the mountain and hopefully having some medals to show for it. I was born after several hours of fetal distress and a lack of oxygen causing permanent brain damage in the form of ataxic cerebral palsy, generalized dystonia, and cervical dystonia. To make some big words small, its hard for me to balance at times, my head shakes constantly, and my hands tremor badly enough that ever since about second grade I’ve had to use a computer to write things down and complete my school work. And then there’s the people that meet me and think I’m just a heroin junkie, but that’s another story. As I grew up I didn’t really find learning to walk with the assistance of a walker or riding a three wheeled bicycle was weird or not normal until about second grade. Due to the tremors in my hands I couldn’t write down the day’s writing assessment, and this was when I started to cry. The reason being was that I wasn’t like the other kids, but little did I know that no-one really cared about anything in elementary school except getting to recess on time and trading up your cold lunch as much as possible so that you got the best lunch at the table. As I grew older I started to realize that my disability was more of a discussion topic than a reason for people not to converse with me. By the time I outgrew my first board I found that it was time to step my game up. I got decked out with the best board I could find and soon got out to Colorado for the first time. It was when I got out to Colorado that I thought, “I could so do this for a living!”. And now, that is exactly what I want to do. My mom is a teacher’s aid at the local high school and my dad is a screen printer, and I just got a minimum wage job, which is why I need sponsorship for my travels to training camps and snowboardcross competitions. If you could find a way to get me connected with any corporate sponsors, organizations who sponsor kids like me, or individual people that you think may be interested to hear my story, my thanks will be endless. If you love powder days out on the mountain, then you must understand my yearn to be able to spend my life living my dream snowboarding.
</p>
<h4 class="peppy">Be Social</h4>
<p>
A website like mine thrives on you-the viewer- being social. As you may have seen, I threw up some socialte buttons at the top of the page. Though it may sound cheesy, sharing is caring in my world. The more people who see the site, the more energy it has behind it, and energy is what I need to keep doing what I love.
</p>
<h4 class="peppy">Updates and More</h4>
<p>
So, you see my site, but want know what I'm doing. You are supporting me, so I don't mind internet stalkers. Check out my blog <a href="http://cjcahala.tumblr.com/">here</a> and from there, you will see links to follow me on twitter or get all caught up on my Youtube uploads (plus many other ways to network with me), all of which are awesome non-productive ways to spend time on the internet. If you want come check out my <a href="http://cjcahala.tumblr.com/">Blog</a>
</p>
<h4 class="peppy">Want To Learn More About Me</h4>
<p>
If you really want to know more about me or if you have a media inquiry, send me an email at <a href="mailto:is-cj@anche.no">is-cj@anche.no</a>
<h1 class="peppy">Contacting Me</h1>
<p class="lead">
To contact me please email me at <a href="mailto:is-cj@anche.no">is-cj@anche.no</a>. The social networking buttons at the top of the page can also be used to connect with me. If you wish to donate, you can click on the donate button below and be sure to put "This donation is for CJ Cahala" in the "notes" section of the Adaptive Adventures donate page. If you have any donation questions, you can send me an email again at <a href="mailto:is-cj@anche.no">is-cj@anche.no</a>.
</p>
<h1 class="peppy">Check Out My Videos</h1>
<p>
<!--Video player-->
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/InaOC5h2Ebo?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<!--Video Description-->
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FjLxq/) that seems to work fine.

Comment: @Jmh2013 Are you sure about that? Make the preview window very small and then scroll to the right. You'll see the error he is talking about.

Comment: @TylerH You're right,I missed the part about scrolling right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` under the `.left` class.

```
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top:0; bottom: 0;
    width: 125px;
    background: #3498db;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FjLxq/2/)**

Comment: Here the sidebar is only as tall as the initial screen height. If you make it too small and then have to scroll down, the rest of the menu is invisible.

Comment: Now is there any way to still keep the functionality of the text following the view-port as you scroll vertically? I know I put the position:absolute; in to allow for always seeing the sidebar while scrolling.

Comment: So you want the menu to always be on the screen? Then you would have to use `position: fixed;` like you were. But set a high `z-index` on your .left class so the text goes under the menu instead of over, when scrolling right.